# Dynamic chunks of preferred list of sizes

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split

So I've run into a little snag of chunk balance.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a list of n length (most often between 400 and 10000)

I want this chunked up and sent to an array of workers, to be processes simultaneously.

So here is my requirements.

The number of chunks should always kept as high as possible, though preferably not above 8 since that is the maximum number that can be processed at a time, any more then 8 chunks will have to be queued.

Chunk length of parts should be kept in containers of even 50's between 250 and 1000 (this makes it a lot easier to track the chunks in the logs)

**Examples**

List length of 1600
6 chunks of 250 and 1 chunks of 100

List length of 3590
7 chunks of 450 and 1 chunks of 440

List of 13000
13 Chunks of 1000 (since the workers can only process a max of 1000)
and I will have to wait for chunks to be completed before I send off new.

I need this be be chosen automatically to maximize efficiency.

Below is a simplified base of what I'm doing

```
public async Task SartSendingJob(int entityId, string body, string reference, IEnumerable<ProcessObject> processingList)
    {
        var jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _jobs.Add(new Job {EntityId = entityId, Id = jobId, ProcessType = ProcessType.Demo});

        var chunks = Split(processingList);

        foreach (var chunk in chunks)
        {
            var process = new Process {JobId = jobId, Id = Guid.NewGuid()};
            _processes.Add(process);

            Sender.SendSimpleMessage("PressRelease", body, reference, chunk.ToList(), process.Id);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var workList = list.ToList();
        int chunksize;
        if (list.Count() > 8000)
        {
            //We know that we can't get lett then 8 chunks of maxumum, so we will use maxumum chunk size
            chunksize = 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            chunksize = CalculateBestChunkSize(workList.Count);
        }

        var sections = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)workList.Count / chunksize);

        int i = 0;

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> splits = workList.GroupBy(item => i++ % sections).Select(part => part.AsEnumerable());
        return splits;

    }

    private int CalculateBestChunkSize(int length)
    {
        //Do some magic
        return 500; //dummy response
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results for those sample inputs.

Comment: Please add some code, we're not here to implement your solutions.

Comment: What was your effort before you run into this problem?

Comment: I don't see why for 1600, 5 chunks of 300 and 1 chunks of 100 is the most efficient. Why not 8 chunks of 200?

Comment: @mjwills but in that same case of 1600, one chunk is 100, which is less than 250.

Comment: Added example code, and sorted miss in calculation of 1600 Example

Comment: And also, the leftover chunk can have a length less then 250.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brain was making this a lot harder then it was.

It needed some coffee to understand what it was actually doing.

Solution to handle it (since we always max out chunk size above maximum threads)

```
    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        int chunkSize;
        if (list.Count() > _maxChunkSize * _maxSendingThreads )
        {
            //We know that we can't get lett then 8 chunks of maxumum, so we will use maxumum chunk size
            chunkSize = 1000;
        }
        else
        {
            //Get the exact number of needed chunksize needed, then round up to nearest 50
            chunkSize = (int) (Math.Ceiling(list.Count / _maxSendingThreads / 50.0) * 50.0);
            if (chunkSize < 250)
            {
                chunkSize = 250;
            }
        }

        var sections = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) list.Count / chunkSize);

        int i = 0;

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> splits = list.GroupBy(item => i++ % sections).Select(part => part.AsEnumerable());
        return splits;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] lengths = { 45, 200, 1600, 3500, 13000 };

            foreach (int len in lengths)
            {

                int totalLen = len;
                do
                {
                    int processLen = totalLen > 8000 ? 8000 : totalLen;
                    totalLen -= 8000;

                    int numChunks = 8;
                    int chunkSize = 0;
                    for (; (numChunks > 0) && (chunkSize < 50); numChunks--)
                    {
                        chunkSize = processLen / numChunks;
                    }
                    chunkSize = 50 * (chunkSize / 50);
                    int lastChunk = processLen - (chunkSize * numChunks);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Number of Chunks '{0}', Chunk Size = '{1}', Total Size = '{2}'", numChunks, chunkSize, (numChunks * chunkSize) + lastChunk);
                } while (totalLen > 0);



            }

        }
    }



}
```